# A limit of sine Question.

Tags: limits

How would I show that the limit of

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi(1+(-1)^nn)}{2(1+n)}\right)$$

doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

$$\sin\big(\frac{\pi(1+(-1)^{2n}2n)}{2(1+2n)}\big)=??$$

$$\sin\big(\frac{\pi(1+(-1)^{2n+1}(2n+1))}{2(1+(2n+1))}\big)=??$$

Comment: thanks i got the limits to be $1$ and $-1$, hence im assuming as theyre different the limit doesnt exist?

Comment: yes... that is it...